# How to filter my tablet version app in google play whcih used uses-feature telephony in android?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, android-market-filtering

I developed and android application and uploaded in google play for mobiles. Now i did the tablet version with same functionality. In my tablet version i used `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony">` attribute which is used for phone calling services. I developed my application for both calling supported and unsupported tablets.Here i want to show my tablet version for only tablets even those are enabled/disabled with calling functionality. 
I know one thing like below which will filter application play store and show the application only for android mobiles.

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true"/>
```

Is there any other way which will filter my application and make available for only tablets( calling function enabled/disabled)

Please advice me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can put on your manifest the support screen size xlarge and then the phone version you put support screen size small, medium, large.
Also you can check on the google play publish site the multiple APKs thing. I never used by I reckon it's used exactly for that.

Comment: Here i have a problem. Xlarge attribute is available from api level 8. but my app is api level 7 only. And some posts saying that is not 100% surely.

Comment: change the project build target to 8. But don't change the UsesSDK on the manifest. Also check the multiple APK thing from the google play, might be easier.

Comment: Most of our app user are api level 7 only. we cont change that

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to tell you. Yes you can! As long as you don't use any API8+ functionality it will work fine on any API7 device.